# Class Library (.NET Core) vs PCL in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android, .net-core, portable-class-library

I am playing with .NET Standard and found strange that if I have the following project.json specified for both a .NET Core class library (xproj) and a Portable Class Library (csharp), only the latter can be properly referenced from a Xamarin.Android project:

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.4": {}
  }
}
```

I can add both as a reference, `dotnet update` works as expected (or at least no error messages shown), but the .NET core library is not realized:

> type or namespace could not be found

I find this strange, since I'd expect any .NET standard targeting library to work properly. Am I doing something wrong or intentionally only PCLs are supported from Xamarin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have a `.csproj` for the Xamarin.Android project and an `.xproj` for your .NET Core class library, which is targeting .NET Standard.

I *believe* the issue might be because of the different project systems we currently have and where each of them expects to find built assemblies for project references.

A workaround is to manually edit the `.csproj` to include the reference with the correct hint path. For example:

```
<Reference Include="SomeOtherClassLibrary">
    <HintPath>..\SomeOtherClassLibrary\bin\$(Configuration)\netstandard1.6\SomeOtherClassLibrary.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

You may also need to manually add a build dependency from the Xamarin.Android to the class library project to ensure the projects are built in the correct order (right click the Xamarin.Android project in Solution Explorer `Build Dependencies > Project Dependencies...`).

In summary, it's not that .NET Standard targeted libraries don't work with Xamarin, or that Xamarin only supports PCLs. It's a quirk with project references and the current state of the tooling, which I am sure will improve in time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works, although I think I'll stick with PCLs until an improvement arrives.